# In which order are pac4j client used

Tags: pac4j

I have an application using pac4j and use multiple authentication clients to secure my routes (both direct and indirect) like this: `Secure("AnonymousClient", "FacebookClient", "JWTClient")`.
I don't really understand in which order the clients are used though. It seems to be from right to left and 401 is returned if none of the clients could build a profile. Am I right?
Is it the same order for the authorizers?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be much more complicated than that. From the comments in DefaultSecurityLogic.java:

> First, if the user is not authenticated (no profile) and if some
> clients have been defined in the clients parameter, a login is tried
> for the direct clients.
>
> Then, if the user has profile, authorizations are checked according to
> the authorizers configuration. If the authorizations are valid, the
> user is granted access. Otherwise, a 403 error page is displayed.
>
> Finally, if the user is still not authenticated (no profile), he is
> redirected to the appropriate identity provider if the first defined
> client is an indirect one in the clients configuration. Otherwise, a
> 401 error page is displayed.